# IsText and IsNumber functions from VBA got invalid results compared with IsText and IsNumber functions from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I encountered several problems when I wanted to validate a column with dates, when I used **IsText** or **IsNumber** function in VBA and then when I noticed the wrong results, I compared the same function directly in Excel.

I was even more surprised to see that the two functions from VBA do not give the same result with the functions from Excel

My VBA code is:

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To 5
    sh.Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(sh.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    sh.Cells(i, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(sh.Cells(i, 1).Value)

    sh.Cells(i, 10).Value = IsDate(sh.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    sh.Cells(i, 9).Value = IsNumeric(sh.Cells(i, 1).Value)
Next i

End Sub
```

And below are the results:

In column **D** I have the result from **IsText** function from VBA and in column **E** I have the results from **IsText** function from Excel.

And similar, in column **E** I have the result from **IsNumber** function from VBA and in column **G** I have the results from **IsNumber** function from Excel.

As you already see the results are different. So what is the explanation?

[image]

Another weird thing was with VBA **IsDate** function where I have different results from 2 Virtual Machines but with the same OS date format. You can see the results in the clumn **J**.
[image]

Comment: They are programmed to different standards. VBA is a wrapper around the COM Automation libraries. These libraries do all conversions and formatting. Excel predates COM and predates VBA (it used to run Excel Basic). It is compatible with all decisions taken years and years ago so your sheets work when you upgrade.

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question. When future readers look at this question and the file is just a dead link, it will not do anyone any good, plus linking to files that have code in them can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Bob,

In your VBA code you don't declare a type for the return of the ISTEXT therefore it is by default a Variant.

Here's some test code I ran in the Immediate window to demonstrate this:

```
x = Cells(3,1)
?x
May-10-22
?VarType(x)
 8
```

If you look up the VarType function you'll see that 8 is String so ISNumber is going to return False and ISText is True as all values will be in when imported into VBA w/o a type declaration.

References:
[Variant Variable Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type)
[VarType Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)